# NTFS Disk mounting in mint

Tags: linux-mint

[image]

can't mount my hard disk with ntfs file format in linux mint

Comment: Have you restarted Windows and disabled fast restart? Try again after that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to boot Windows:

Run Command prompt as Administrator and type:

```
chkdsk c: /f
```

It will ask if to check upon reboot, say Yes and reboot again into Windows.

After the file system is clean, the problem will be solved.

Just down without hibernation and such.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean shutdown your Windows first, before you can mount the disk in linux.

Please boot your windows, maybe also use `cmd` as administrator for disable hibernation with `powercfg /hibernate off`, and then shut down your Windows cleanly. After that you should be able to mount your drive.